# Group by without aggregation function

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Could anyone give me a simple example of the use of "Group By" WITHOUT any aggregation function?

What does it do? does it sort the results ? I couldn't find any good example without aggregation function..

Comment: It will do error since your question is tagged as __sql__ only. In some DBMS such as MySQL it's allowed but then server is free to choose any row

Comment: ok... so it's like distinct? it selects any row from each different result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the GROUP BY statement in any way useful without an accompanying aggregate function?

You can perform a DISTINCT select by using a GROUP BY without any AGGREGATES.

Using `DISTINCT` would be a synonym in such a situation, but the reason you'd want/have to define a `GROUP BY` clause would be in order to be able to define `HAVING` clause details.

If you need to define a `HAVING` clause, you ***have*** to define a `GROUP BY` - you can't do it in conjunction with `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this

Below Links will helpful for both (with aggregate function and without agreegate function)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm